# SSL通信をしていないローカルマシンに接続して位置情報を取得する方法

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tomcat

Tomcat9で動作するJavascriptです。（動作していませんが）
これをローカルホストで動かし「IPアドレス:ポート」のようにURLに打ち込みブラウザに表示させることは出来ますが
この位置情報を取得するJavaScriptは動かず「位置情報の取得が許可されていません」というエラーになります。
しかしブラウザもスマートフォン端末の設定も許可しています。
SSL通信ではないHTTPだとChromeで位置情報を取得できないのか、とも考えましたが
先月くらいは、この書き方ではないもののJavaScriptで位置情報を取得できていた記憶があります。

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。
不足の情報があればご教示くださいませ。

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var coords = "緯度: " + latitude + ", 経度: " + longitude;
            console.log(coords);
        },
        function(error) {
            var errorMessage = "位置情報の取得に失敗しました。";
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    errorMessage += "位置情報の取得が許可されていません。";
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    errorMessage += "位置情報が利用できません。";
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    errorMessage += "位置情報の取得がタイムアウトしました。";
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    errorMessage += "不明なエラーが発生しました。";
                    break;
        }
            console.error(errorMessage);
    }
        );
    } else {
        console.error("ブラウザが位置情報をサポートしていません。");
}
```

Comment: function(position)が飛ばされてしまう形で処理が終わりエラーが表示されます。

Comment: やはりSSL通信でなければChromeだと弾かれてしまいそうです
localhostだと位置情報を取得できていますし、エラーが「端末で許可されていない」なのでアプリ側でのセキュリティに引っかかっているのでしょう